# Query to fetch objects surrounding an object

Tags: python, database, django

Lets say I am fetching a specific episode of a series.
What would be the best way to get the surrounding episodes by episode number?

Simplified model:

```
class Episode(models.Model):
    series = models.ForeignKey(Series)
    number = models.IntegerField()
```

For example, episode 10 would fetch episodes 8-12.
Episode 1 would fetch episodes 1-5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like you're just treating a TV series as an array of episodes. If that's the case, why not something like

```
Episode.objects.filter(series=some_series,number__gte=epnum-2, number__lte=epnum+2)
```

to find the episodes surrounding the episode `epnum`, with special cases for when `epnum-2<=0` or `epnum+2>Episode.object.filter(series=some_series).order_by('-number')[0].number`?

If you want, say, episodes at a season break to be treated differently, you'll need to do something more complicated, like perhaps what @Scott suggests. But otherwise, I believe this simple solution will suffice.

Comment: Even better, stick this into a Manager.

Answer (score 3):

Building on desfido's solution:

```
class EpisodeManager(models.Manager):
    def get_near_objects(self, series, number):
        return self.get_query_set().filter(
            series=series, 
            number__gte=number-2, 
            number__lte=number+2)

    use_for_related = True
```

Then in your model:

```
class Episode(models.Model):
    series = models.ForeignKey(Series)
    number = models.IntegerField()

    objects = EpisodeManager()
```

Now, you can use:

```
Episode.objects.get_near_objects(series="Star Trek: The Original Series", number=7)
```